# In Islam are you allowed to look at other people kissing?

Tags: halal-haram, kissing

You see If Iam watching a show or anything and there's kissing I don't look at it I just want to know are you allowed to look at that in Islam

Comment: We seek effortful questions showing prior research.  Asking about permissibility without indicating a reason it's not the [default ruling](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36838) is considered [off-topic](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/663).  Please [edit] the question accordingly.  See [How do we answer a question “Is X haram?” when there's no reason to think X is haram?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3305)

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones in this case there's a reason to think X is haram.

Comment: The question doesn't indicate what it is, and doesn't show any research effort.  Also, its score is -2 and after 2 years and 5 months remains without an upvoted answer.  The question is not exactly a masterpiece; why hang onto it?  (If it's an important question, we can let it be asked again, but properly next time.)

Answer (score 0):

Allah has [ordered](http://quran.com/24/30) us to curb our sights from haram things. However, there is no worldly punishment for such actions.

IMO, it is the sort of sins that are washed away by doing good things and asking Allah for forgiveness.